# How do I remove the "&" symbol in my VS Code terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've recently downloaded Anaconda and VS Code. I am trying to run some simple code but I am running into a syntax error because there is an "&" symbol in front of the Anaconda file path. How do I remove this?

```
C:\Users\hkell\Desktop\VS Code> conda activate base
PS C:\Users\hkell\Desktop\VS Code> & C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exeis?
```

Comment: First of all please don't post images of text, copy-paste text as *text*. Secondly, where does the `&` come from? Is it printed by the previous `conda` command? Is it something you happened to copy-paste together with the `python.exe` command? Can't you just to to the beginning of the line and delete it?

Comment: & C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe 
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Here's the syntax error I get with the carrot pointing to the & symbol. It's not something I can change, it comes up when I run code

Comment: Are the commands part of a script or some VSCode configuration file? Have you looked at this script or configuration file?

Comment: It's not part of my script. When I run a program my file path comes up before the output. When I left click on the file path and select "Open File in Editor" I get the following error:

Comment: + SyntaxError: invalid syntax    & C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe  ...
+                                ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass    
it as part of a string.

Comment: I don't know how I got the ampersand there to begin with though. I can't just click in the terminal and remove it